# How to delete text from textArea in AS3, generated from another textArea

Tags: actionscript-3

I didn't know how to explain this in the title, but I have a textArea that generates text in another textArea in my application. It generates the text just fine:

```
gallery.txtArea1.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, displayEvent);

function displayEvent(event:TextEvent):void {
        picArea1.text = gallery.txtArea1.text + event.text;
}
```

But when I want to delete text from the dynamic text area picArea1, it doesn't capture that keyCode. So I added another event listener specifically for that:

```
gallery.txtArea1.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPressed);

function onKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DELETE) {
            picArea1.text = gallery.txtArea1.text;
        }
}
```

Just to refresh it. But it doesn't pick up on the delete either. What am I missing?

Comment: try using KEY_UP instead on your second listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Weird issue. When I changed:

```
event.keyCode == Keyboard.DELETE
```

to

```
event.keyCode == 8
```

it started working. I have no idea why this set it off because I imported the Keyboard class and everything. I had to do a little trickery to get only the last character deleted from the string, because the way I coded it, it was taking the entire string and adding the last character to the end, then resampling the whole thing and doing it again:

```
picArea1.text = gallery.txtArea1.text + event.text;
```

So this is my final function:

```
gallery.txtArea1.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPressed);

function onKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (event.keyCode == 8) {
            var newString:String = gallery.txtArea1.text;
            picArea1.text = newString.substring(0, newString.length - 1);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT` method doesn't dispatch on things that don't add to the text input.

Your headed the right direction with adding the a key listener instead.  If you use KEY_UP instead of KEY_DOWN, it should work the way you expect.

The reason being, KEY_DOWN is dispatched/handled before the text input is changed by the system.  Alternatively, you could use a `Timer` and have it update between the KEY_DOWN and KEY_UP events, if you wanted to have instant results when a delete/backspace key is held down to erase multiple letters.

Comment: Naw, it doesn't work when I do KEY_UP either. I don't know what's going on.